# How to create key->value mapping in MySQL smartly?

Tags: mysql

I want to query severity/facility from syslog, and translate then from number to meaningful keywords like this:

```
select case severity 
when 0 then 'emerg'
when 1 then 'Alert'
when 2 then 'Crit'
when 3 then 'Error'
when 4 then 'Warn'
when 5 then 'Notice'
when 6 then 'Info'
when 7 then 'Debug'
end,   

case facility
when 0 then 'kern'
when 1 then 'user'
...
when 23 then 'local7'
end
from logs.sys_log;
```

While the range of severity is from 0 to 7, and the range of facility is from 0 to 23.
I will get a very long query string.
Is there any smarter method to create key->value mapping in MySQL, to shorten the query string ?

Comment: What does [My]SQL have to do with the query string again? The information in the database and how a query is represented in a URI resource are two different concepts - although a 1:1 mapping usually makes things "easier" to keep in order. The only issue is to make sure that keys that are stable across the URI lifetime such that there are no accidental cross-queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new tables `severity_mapping` and `facility_mapping` with two columns:

- number
- value

And store the data `0-emerg` etc. to first table and `0-kern` to the second. Later, use JOIN clauses in your query.

Comment: Will it be more efficient using a function severity_to_str(key) to implement mappings?

Comment: @Brightshine I'm not familiar with `severity_to_str` function. A link to its documentation?

Comment: My original design is writing a custom function : string severity_to_str(int). severity_to_str(0) will return 'emerg', and severity_to_str(1) will return 'Alert'...